# Getting the error "Exception: The starting column of the range is too small." in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is the code

```
 
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
 

const RECIPIENT_COL  = "Recipient";
const EMAIL_SENT_COL = "Email Sent";
 
/** 
 * Creates the menu item "Mail Merge" for user to run scripts on drop-down.
 */
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Mail Merge')
      .addItem('Send Emails', 'sendEmails')
      .addToUi();
}
 

function sendEmails(subjectLine, sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
  // option to skip browser prompt if you want to use this code in other projects
  if (!subjectLine){
    subjectLine = Browser.inputBox("Mail Merge", 
                                      "Type or copy/paste the subject line of the Gmail " +
                                      "draft message you would like to mail merge with:",
                                      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
                                      
    if (subjectLine === "cancel" || subjectLine == ""){ 
    // if no subject line finish up
    return;
    }
  }
  
  const emailTemplate = getGmailTemplateFromDrafts_(subjectLine);
  
  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();

  const data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

  const heads = data.shift(); 
  
  const emailSentColIdx = heads.indexOf(EMAIL_SENT_COL);
  
  const obj = data.map(r => (heads.reduce((o, k, i) => (o[k] = r[i] || '', o), {})));


  const out = [];

  obj.forEach(function(row, rowIdx){
    // only send emails is email_sent cell is blank and not hidden by filter
    if (row[EMAIL_SENT_COL] == ''){
      try {
        const msgObj = fillInTemplateFromObject_(emailTemplate.message, row);

        GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
          htmlBody: msgObj.html,
          // bcc: 'a.bbc@email.com',
          // cc: 'a.cc@email.com',
          // from: 'an.alias@email.com',
          // name: 'name of the sender',
          // replyTo: 'a.reply@email.com',
          // noReply: true, // if the email should be sent from a generic no-reply email address (not available to gmail.com users)
          attachments: emailTemplate.attachments,
          inlineImages: emailTemplate.inlineImages
        });
        // modify cell to record email sent date
        out.push([new Date()]);
      } catch(e) {
        // modify cell to record error
        out.push([e.message]);
      }
    } else {
      out.push([row[EMAIL_SENT_COL]]);
    }
  });
  

  sheet.getRange(2, emailSentColIdx+1, out.length).setValues(out);
```

I am not entirely sure why that error is showing up. It is for sure in the following line of code so I changed it a bit from

```
 sheet.getRange(2, emailSentColIdx+1, out.length).setValues(out);
```

to

```
 sheet.getRange(2, emailSentColIdx+2, out.length).setValues(out);
```

It completed the script but would not actually send those emails/carry out the functions intended.
When I output Logger.log(out), I get the following:

```
[[null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null]]
```

This question is different from the already asked similar question because it was missing a key detail in sheets side of things.
I have gone on to fix it. There was no issue with the actual column, it just missed one of the values.

Comment: I woiuld say that emailSentColIdx is equal to a -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that emailSentColIdx is equal to a -1  Which causes the column to be zero on this line: `sheet.getRange(2, emailSentColIdx+1, out.length).setValues(out);` Column and Row numbers start at one

This is the line causing the problem: `const emailSentColIdx = heads.indexOf(EMAIL_SENT_COL);` Perhaps you have a space in your header line I can't tell without seeing a copy of your sheet

Comment: You are right, emailSentColIdx is outputting -1. The output for heads is an array: [Period, Room Number, Resident, Recipient, Balance Forward, Deposits, Social Activities, Hair Services, Guest Meals, Foot Care, Refunds, Balance]

Comment: Yeah so you are missing `Email Sent`